# Flask - Why doesn't this let me import image files?

Tags: python, image, flask, file-upload, cs50

I am trying to make an application that allows users to upload images from their computer. This is as part of my CS50x final project, so I'm working in the CS50 IDE. Here is the code for my application:

***application.py***

```
import os
from flask import *  
app = Flask(__name__)  

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER     
 
@app.route('/')  
def myindex():
    return render_template("file_upload_form.html")  
 
@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])  
def upload():  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        file = request.files['file']  
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "test.jpg"))
        return redirect("/")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

***file_upload_form.html***

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>upload</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form action = "/upload" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
        <input type="file" name="file" />  
        <input type = "submit" value="Upload">  
    </form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

For the vast majority of files, when I submit the form, I get a *500 Internal Server Error* with no traceback or explanation. Curiously though, some files it seems to work with. I have found two images that work: both JPEGs and both relatively small. All other images I have tried have caused the error.

I cannot work out what is causing the Server Error, or why some images work and others don't. Can anyone see any reason why it wouldn't work for other images?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the `post` to: `<form action = "/success"...>`

Where is your `/success` handler?

**UPDATE:**

Try:

```
if request.method == 'POST':  
    print(request.files)
    print(request.form)
    print(request.POST)
```

You need to check the logs to see what there error is.

Comment: Oops - I changed the name of the function in application.py before posting it here. Thanks for pointing that out. It matches up in the app now, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: I replaced the 'POST' route with that code, and it threw an error before it printed anything. I think the problem must be that it never makes the 'POST' request in the first place!

Comment: How about just 'print(request)’?

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your code and it worked fine on my side, but there is a couple of additions i would make, just to make it more robust.

You are calling all your uploads test.jpg and there is no mechanism in place to ensure that the file that gets uploaded is a jpg file. So technically, i could upload a pdf and it would be renamed in to a test.jpg.
A better method is to just give the file - the same name it had, including the extension. If you want to re-name the file, rather strip the extension first and add it to the new filename like so:

```
ext = file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
newFilename = 'newname.{}'.format(ext)
```

Also there is no MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH - I would add that as well.

So i re-wrote your python code to look like this:

```
import os
from flask import *
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['ALLOWED_IMAGES'] = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

def allowed_image(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in app.config['ALLOWED_IMAGES']

@app.route('/')
def myindex():

    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']

        if file and allowed_image(file.filename):

            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file.filename)))
            return redirect(request.url)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding those extra features! I still have the same problem though; only a select few images will upload. Most will throw a '500 Internal Server Error'. I appreciate the help! –